# Gatsby Webhooks and how to trigger the build from Strapi

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, strapi

we are currently working on connecting the **Strapi** cms with the gatsby on the front end.
My question is - do we need to set up the **Webhooks** to trigger the build inside of the repo on the **Bit Bucket** or it needs to be triggered on a hosting?

If you know the solution I would really appreciate it if you could share the procedure with me cause I'm seeing a lot of different cases online but I wasn't able to find this specific one.

Our hosting is **AWS S3**, and **Gatsby** is fetching the data from **Strapi** via **GraphQL**.

Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that is deleted from the documentation - https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/daaf1392d217a5927ea40320881bfec3208c9927/docs/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/webhooks.md

That uses the model's life cycles but you can apply this logic with the new Webhook feature that is now builtin Strapi.